# Type checking a method call with a default argument prior to keyword argument dictionary

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Given

```py
def f_with_opt(opt_arg: bool | None = None, **kwargs):
    print(f"{opt_arg=}, {kwargs=}")


def function() -> None:
    kwargs = {"foo": "bar"}
    f_with_opt(**kwargs)  # mypy complains about this line


if __name__ == "__main__":
    function()
```

mypy reports

```
test.py:7:18: error: Argument 1 to "f_with_opt" has incompatible type "**Dict[str, str]"; expected "Optional[bool]"  [arg-type]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

How can I properly annotate the methods to avoid this error? I've taken a look at https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/ but I don't think it helps in this case. Or does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching a bit I came across this GitHub issue: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5382

And so following this issue, you can fix simply by typing your dictionary with `dict[str, Any]`
Ex:

```
    kwargs: dict[str, Any] = {"foo": "bar"}
```

Or you can create a TypedDict, but depending on what you want to do with your dictionary this may seem a bit overkill.

Comment: Indeed that solves it! I suppose that mypy is ussing the inferred type of the calling kwargs to apply to all arguments of the called function. Seems like a bug to me, because the call did match the type annotations of the declared function.

Comment: @JuanT it's certainly not a bug. `mypy` does not (and should not, IMO) try to guess literal  TypedDict type when you define a dictionary. So `{'foo': 1, 'bar': 'bar'}` is a `dict[str, object]` and not `TypedDict({'foo': int, 'bar': str})`. Python is not typescript, fortunately, and python dict is not js Object.

Comment: Are we talking about the same thing? Mypy complains about this call `f_with_opt(**kwargs)` no matching the function's signature. I've commented the code to make it clear which line mypy complains about